cephadm does not add mon-daemon after add host
I have a cephadm-managed ceph-cluster consisting of 2 nodes.
When trying to add a third node, cephadm says it was successful:
main@node01:~$ sudo ceph orch host add node03 10.0.0.155
Added host 'node03' with addr '10.0.0.155'

Checking the cluster however shows this isn't the case:
main@node01:~$ sudo ceph node ls
{
    "mon": {
        "node01": [
            "node01"
        ],
        "node02": [
            "node02"
        ]
    },
    "osd": {},
    "mgr": {
        "node01": [
            "node01.gnxkpe"
        ],
        "node02": [
            "node02.tdjwgc"
        ]
    }
}

Edit: changed the title - apparently the host is added, but the mon daemon is not started.
main@node01:~$ sudo ceph orch host ls
HOST    ADDR        LABELS  STATUS  
node01  10.0.0.101  _admin          
node02  10.0.0.131  _admin          
node03  10.0.0.155  _admin          
3 hosts in cluster

main@node01:~$ sudo ceph status
  cluster:
    id:     cab58bfb-9cef-11ef-a862-408d5c51323a
    health: HEALTH_WARN
            1 failed cephadm daemon(s)
            failed to probe daemons or devices
            OSD count 0 < osd_pool_default_size 3
 
  services:
    mon: 2 daemons, quorum node01,node02 (age 3h)
    mgr: node01.gnxkpe(active, since 6h), standbys: node02.tdjwgc
    osd: 0 osds: 0 up, 0 in

main@node01:~$ sudo ceph orch daemon add mon node03
Error EINVAL: name mon.node03 already in use


what is result of ceph orch host ls ?

Hi, that would be
HOST    ADDR        LABELS  STATUS node01  10.0.0.101  _admin node02 10.0.0.131 node03 10.0.0.155 3 hosts in cluster - seems like they are all added, but only node01 is admin, and mgr and mon only run on the first 2.

I just tried to add the mon to node03: sudo ceph orch daemon add mon node03 gave me Error EINVAL: name mon.node03 already in use.

in my ceph version (pacific), when adding a node, one can specify --labels=mon (or more function). However, I don't know how to add it afterward (hence this a comment)

Please share the output of: ceph orch ls mon --export. You might want to run: ceph orch apply mon -- placement=„count:3“, alternatively you can specify the hosts in the placement parameter. Or even better: create a spec file that contains the required hosts. There are several ways. If the cli command doesn’t work, you’ll need to inspect the logs of the active mgr.

[sudo] password for main: 
service_type: mon
service_name: mon
placement:
  count: 5```. The `placement` command says `invalid command`

I found that node03 had some leftovers from a previous installation. I did a complete removal of the ceph-installation on that node, including removing /etc/ceph, now everything is working as expected.
